# /etc/pam.d/login vs. /etc/pam.d/system-auth

Tags: linux, security, pam

I want to enforce password complexity on my RH system (local authentication) and have discovered that I need a pam module line something similar to this:

```
password  required pam_cracklib.so dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=0 minlen=8
```

My question is should I be altering /etc/pam.d/login or /etc/pam.d/system-auth and what is the difference between the two files?

Comment: Can someone correct the subject to have the correct slashes?

Comment: What's wrong with the slashes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want system-auth.  It is a "generic" set of PAM parameters used by (typically) all services on the system.  The `login` service is used by (unsurprisingly) the `/bin/login` program (which is invoked for logins to virtual consoles only).  If you add that line to `/etc/pam.d/login`, then only password changes initiated by the login program would have the complexity requirements enforced (and, in case you're wondering, login doesn't do password changes).

Answer (score 3):

System-auth is for all types of login, including ssh

login is just for local console (NOT remote login)

Comment: Thanks Mattymo for your answer but I had to go with womble for the more thorough explanation.