# The difference between /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/system-auth?

Tags: linux, security, rhel5, pam

I want to configure securetty to limit root directly access. Now I am clear if I add:

```
auth        required      pam_securetty.so
```

into /etc/pam.d/system-auth, and keep only "console" in /etc/securetty, ssh login will also be prohibit.
And if I add:

```
auth        required      pam_securetty.so
```

into /etc/pam.d/login, and keep only "console" in /etc/securetty, ssh login will not be prohibit.

Now I am not very clear about the difference between /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/system-auth. Could anyone give me some reference or some guide?
Thanks a lot!

P.S. 
[/etc/pam.d/login vs. /etc/pam.d/system-auth](https://serverfault.com/questions/20830/etc-pam-d-login-vs-etc-pam-d-system-auth)
also give a little about it, but I want to get more to make me more clear.

Comment: Could you be more exact? What are you missing from the link? It explains the differences between the both files.

Comment: Christian, yes, in fact, the link makes me clear about the problem. But I want to know if there are more difference because I am not sure if the answer "login is just for local console (NOT remote login)" in the link is right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file is used by Red-Hat and like systems to group together common security policies. It is often included in other `/etc/pam.d` policy files where those common policies are required.

When accessing a system via ssh through sshd, the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` policy file is consulted. This file includes `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` so your changes to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` are valid.

The file `/etc/pam.d/login` is consulted when you log in via the `/bin/login` program therefore any changes to it only affect `/bin/login`.

Answer (score 5):

- login - rules for local (console login)
- system-auth - common rules many services
- password-auth - common rules for many remote services
- sshd - rules for SSHD daemon only

Answer (score 3):

> Now I am not very clear about the difference between /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/system-auth. Could anyone give me some reference or some guide?

OpenSSH use /etc/pam.d/sshd module. /etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
auth       include      system-auth
```

OpenSSH not use /etc/pam.d/login to auth. /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/system-auth is different modules to different programs.

Comment: bindbn, thanks for your explanations and suggestions. I got your meaning "etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/system-auth is different modules to different programs".